# What is rate of strain hardening?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, continuum-mechanics

This is what a random search gives me,"Rate of change of true stress as a function of true strain in a material undergoing plastic deformation."as far as the definition of rate of strain is concerend.Mathematically it is expressed as $d(log $$\sigma$)/d(log$\epsilon)$.However I do not understand why we refer to this as "rate"?where is the time factor coming in from?Please explain with close reference to the strain hardening equation.

Comment: Particularly with the last sentence, the appears to be a homework question. Now, since the expression is the ratio of two derivatives, why is it not a rate of change?

Comment: @JonCuster It is not a homework question.It just cropped up in my mind

Comment: Also @JonCuster  "since the expression is the ratio of two derivatives, why is it not a rate of change" do you mean change in y wrt x?